# How to access filtered range in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function that should return the filtered column of a named table. Filtering is working fine but the result is always the unfiltered column. What is my mistake?

```
Function getFilteredColumn(ByVal sSheetName As String, ByVal sTableName As String, ByVal sSearchColumn As  String, ByVal sSearchText As String, ByVal sResultColumn As String) As Variant
  Set lo = Sheets(sSheetName).ListObjects(sTableName)
  searchCol = lo.ListColumns(sSearchColumn).Index
  resultCol = lo.ListColumns(sResultColumn).Index
  lo.range.AutoFilter Field:=searchCol, Criteria1:=sSearchText 'Filter range
  getFilteredColumn = Application.Transpose(lo.range.Columns(resultCol).Value) ' Error: always the unfiltered range is returned
  lo.range.AutoFilter Field:=searchCol 'unset filter
 
End Function
```

Comment: You need to loop the `Areas` of the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` and read their values into an array. Or copy the cells to a new sheet, and then read the `.Value` of the copied range. Also, it's recommended to avoid using `Transpose` and just work with the 2D array returned by `.Value`.

Comment: Thanks but that means if have to loop the cells anyway I can skip the filter and just parse and filter the lines manually.